# PHP PDO: gets first column from query

Tags: php, pdo

I have a pretty stupid question, but I can't get it to work immediately.
How do I load only one field of the result array of a query into a session (array) using a single PDO statement?
I commented the missing code below:

```
public function getPermissions($user_role_id){
    if(!isset($user_role_id) || empty($user_role_id)){ 
        $_SESSION['user']['user_permissions'] = '';
    }else{
        $db = Database::get_database();
        $query = "
            SELECT 
                rp.role_id, rp.permission_id 
            FROM 
                role_permission_tbl rp 
            WHERE
                rp.role_id = :role_id"; 

            $query_params = array( 
                ':role_id' => $user_role_id
            );

            try 
            {
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex) 
            { 
                 die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
            }

            $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
            if($row){
                //I only want to retrieve the field "permission_id" 
                $_SESSION['user']['user_permissions'] = $row;
            }else{
                $_SESSION['user']['user_permissions'] = '';
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: may be you should try any other fetch method?

Comment: I looked for it, but couldn't find a convenient method.

Comment: use fetch() instead of fetchAll()..

Comment: fetch will only return one row to me; I need to feth the array of permissions.

Comment: in what form you want all these permissions? array? string?

Comment: Preferrably into an array. I will use in_array later to check if a certain permission_id is present in the array.

Comment: you cannot use in_array on string, but for some reason always trying assign an empty string to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other "get it to work immediately" this question has contradicting conditions.
Like any other PHP code, it is ten times long than needed.
Like many other SO questions, it can be solved by quick manual lookup.

In case you need your permissions in array

```
public function getPermissions($user_role_id){
    $sql = "SELECT permission_id FROM role_permission_tbl WHERE role_id = ?"; 
    $stm = Database::get_database()->prepare($sql);
    return $stm->execute(array($user_role_id))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}
```

note that assigning variables inside functions is a very bad practice. So, better call it this way

```
$_SESSION['user']['user_permissions'] = $user->getPermissions($user_role_id);
```

- isset() is useless in conjunction with empty() as latter covers the former.
- both isset() and empty() are useless for the function variable too, as it is always set by design
- a verification for this particular input variable can be done, but for the sanely designed application it would be unnecessary.
- setting a variable you are going to test with in_array() to an empty string will produce an error.
- there is no use for the alias with single table.
- PDO methods can be called dramatically shorter way, there is no use for stretching one simple query call to a whole screen of code.
- echoing a system error message to a site user is an awful practice.
- the very manual page for the fetchAll() contains an exact example for this very question of getting single column out of the query result.
- there is no use for testing returned value explicitly, as it already contains either result or empty value (and luckily, fetchAll() will return even empty value of desired type).

Comment: +1 Uh I'm an idiot. Although your code doesn't seem to execute for me, I should just have not added the role_id in the select statement. This error occurred because I have been making a lot of joins, and somehow my brain told me that I had to include the role_id as well to fulfill the where statement.

Comment: What you mean "doesn't seem to execute"? Doesn't it seem or doesn't execute?

Comment: what does it say? did you make it recommended way? did you try understand what it does instead of just copy/pasteing it?

Comment: I'm looking at it as we speak. Although I obviously made a stupid mistake; if this code is faster, then I will see how it works.

Comment: This code is ten times better than yours in dozen different aspects, not the only "faster" one you can think of.

Comment: If you are using an outdated PHP version, try this one

Comment: Awesome, I got it working. Great tips of things I didn't know; thanks for the lessons.

Comment: I just added some more

Comment: Makes all sense, but I can only upvote it once. I will give more attention to these points towards the future; since I'm still in a learning phase.

Answer (score 4):

After seeing your later comments, it looks as though you're wanting to save all permission data in a session variable so that you can look it up by permission ID:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row){
    //Add to session, keyed by permission ID.
    $_SESSION['user']['user_permissions'][$row['permission_id']] = $row;
}

//Then, if you want to see if said permission ID #21 exists:
if(isset($_SESSION['user']['user_permissions'][21])){
    echo 'This user has permissions with ID 21!';
    $permissionDetails = $_SESSION['user']['user_permissions'][21];
    var_dump($permissionDetails);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this returns to me only the first permission_id. I would like to obtain all the permission id's related to that user into the session variable.

Comment: @KimGysen You can loop through the array $row if you're dealing with multiple rows.

Comment: Indeed; this would be my second option. However, I didn't think it would be necessary. Thanks anyhow

Comment: @KimGysen Are you wanting to assign all columns to your session variable?

Comment: +1 for providing me a solutions that works. But you know, I'm a real idiot. I should just have deleted the role_id on the left side of the select statement. Because I have been making a lot of inner joins, my brain somehow assumed that I had to include the role_id to fulfill the where clause.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What do you mean?

Comment: sorry, I shouldn't have left that comment at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense No, I was just wondering if you disagreed with my method.

Comment: It is too direct in approach (there are better ways), it doesn't answer the question (how to get a column, not array of rows) and it is wrong with implementation (there is no use for the grouping results)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I had originally told OP how to get a particular column. However, the goal post was shifted later on via his/her comments. And grouping the results by permission ID would make it easier to search to see if the logged in user has a particular permission.

Comment: @WayneWhitty I'm sorry for the confusion; with field, I actually referred to the column (row -> record, column -> field). I'll use the term column in the future to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `$row = $stmt-> fetch();` instead of `$row = $stmt->fetchAll();` if it is fetch only one record from table,

```
 $row["permission_id"];
```

Comment: I need to capture the array. Thank